# How to add an object during ListIterator (reversed) iteration properly?

Tags: java, insert, iterator, infinite-loop

I have been asked from my professor to add an object in the middle of an `ArrayedList<Employee>` using listiterator.

I have tried doing in the following way first:

```
ListIterator < Employee > li = emps.listIterator(emps.size());

System.out.println("\nUsing ListIterator:\n");

i = 1;
while (li.hasPrevious()) {
    if (li.nextIndex() == 5) {
        li.add(emp_M);
    }

    System.out.println("  Employee " + (i++) + " " + li.previous());
}
```

But this produces a seemingly infinite number of iterations where `li.nextIndex()` gets stuck on 5.
I have verified this with the debugger and this happens only after `li.add(emp_M)` is evaluated.

I have found a solution where I added a `break` right after `li.add(emp_M)` and continued parsing the list separately in the same way but without adding to the list `emp_M` at all:

```
//parse in two loops to add the middle employee, without the break the list seemingly spirals into infinity!
System.out.println("\nUsing ListIterator:\n");
i = 1;
while (li.hasPrevious()) {
    if (li.nextIndex() == 5) {
        li.add(emp_M);
        System.out.println("ADDED IN MIDDLE");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("  Employee " + (i++) + " " + li.previous());
}

while (li.hasPrevious()) {
    System.out.println("  Employee " + (i++) + " " + li.previous());
}
```

This left me wondering, is what I did a lazy and naive approach? How else can I add to a list with `listIterator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you will add the element `emp_M` indefinitely.

If we go through one iteration where you add an element:

Suppose `li.nextIndex() == 5`, then you will add a new element to your iterator, and according to the documentation of [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)), you will also increase by one your index (hence you move your iterator to the right). Then your loops continues and you move your iterator to the left with `li.previous()`, which happens to be place before you added the element (and verifies the if condition to add).

Now, you start a new iteration of your while loop, verifies the condition again, add a new element ect... You will stay stuck at the element verifying the condition by adding indefinitely new elements.

To make the code easier, try to run your iterator in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) direction (ie `e1 -> e2 -> e3 -> e4`)

```
ListIterator < Employee > li = emps.listIterator();

i = 1;
while (li.hasNext()) {
    if (li.nextIndex() == 5) {
        li.add(emp_M);
    }

    System.out.println("  Employee " + (i++) + " " + li.next());
}
```

Comment: Thank you but my professor specifically asked for doing the list in reverse, I suppose he anticipated this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it after digging deeper in the debugger.

At the moment before adding `li.nextIndex() == 5` and `li.previousIndex() == 4`
After adding the object the aforementioned change to `li.nextIndex() == 6` and `li.previousIndex() == 5` this is because listIterator's `.add()` inserts the object before `.next()`.

Moving ahead with this problem sets up a back and forth loop where `li.previous()` decreases both `li.previousIndex()` and `li.nextIndex()` by 1, and calling `li.add(emp_M)` increases both aforementioned values by 1.

To fix it, we need to skip the added element after adding:

```
 System.out.println("\nUsing ListIterator:\n"); 
        i = 1;
        while (li.hasPrevious())
        {
            if(li.nextIndex() == 5)
            {
                li.add(emp_M);
                li.previous();
                System.out.println("ADDED IN MIDDLE");
//              break;
            }
            System.out.println("  Employee " + (i++) + " " + li.previous());
        }
```

this effectively negates the problem mentioned above.

Sometimes by simply asking a question you find the answer yourself!

I'm going to delay accepting my own answer if someone can explain it to me better than I understood it.